# Silence google home

Tags: stringify, ifttt

I've recently got a Google Home and have created some simple applets. I've created one to run when I go to bed (it's in the living room). So when I say "Good night", I want it to turn the central heating off, turn the lights out and go silent (it may be playing music). I must admit I was astonished how limited IFTTT is, but I linked it to stringify so I could perform more than one action in an applet. However, I can't find anything to silence the Google Home. Has anyone any suggestions? Ideally through stringify but as a separate applet if necessary.

Apologies if there's somewhere obvious to find this information, googling for anything just gets a load of adverts!

Answer (score 1):

For routines that I want to run silently, I add the custom command `Turn on Night Mode` at the beginning of the routine. This requires that you have previously gone to the device settings and set your `Night Mode` volume to 0%. You'll also probably want to add the custom command `Turn off Night Mode` at the end of the routine.

Unfortunately, the routine will only run silently when it is activated by voice (i.e. saying "Hey Google, [routine name]"). If the routine starts automatically at a specific time it will still make noise.

Comment: Starting yesterday, putting `Hey Google, turn on Night Mode` into a routine (or saying it to my Home Mini) gets an `I don't know how to do that` response. I haven't found a fix yet.